# What is type (like "object") in ERC721 Metadata JSON schema

Tags: json, ethereum, cryptocurrency, nft, erc721

According to the [standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721), there's a `type` such as "object" shown below. What is this `type` for and what other types can we use? Can I use like "art?"

```
{
    "title": "Asset Metadata",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Identifies the asset to which this NFT represents"
        },
        "description": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Describes the asset to which this NFT represents"
        },
        "image": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "A URI pointing to a resource with mime type image/* representing the asset to which this NFT represents. Consider making any images at a width between 320 and 1080 pixels and aspect ratio between 1.91:1 and 4:5 inclusive."
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the datatype of the described item according to the [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/specification.html) specification. It's a standard used in other development fields as well - not limited just to NFTs or blockchain development.

There is a list of default allowed `type` values: http://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/type.html

It's possible to create a custom type in JSON Schema, but the limited scope of what the "ERC-721 Metadata Document" document allows, doesn't effectively allow for custom types.

TLDR: Cannot use `type: "art"` in an "ERC-721 Metadata Document". Can use it in a larger scope (e.g. a REST endpoint definition).